# How do I disable private browsing mode in firefox 18?

Tags: firefox

How do I disable private browsing in Firefox 18?

I Tried to look for something on `about:config`, but did not find anything.
I found [This aswer here](https://superuser.com/questions/189327/how-can-i-disable-private-browsing-incognito-mode-in-browser-x), but I was unable to find that file on my computer.

I am using Firefox on Windows 7

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Using the [Disable Private Browsing](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disable-private-browsing/) Firefox extension?

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar: Maybe to monitor what their children are doing?

Comment: I need to do this because my brother is visiting some sites that are not for his age. I've blocked some using the hosts file and even configured a proxy autoconfiguration file to block sites using RegExes, but he still manages to open some sites. I can't make the PAC file more restrictive because it will block some legitmate sites. My plan is to constantly update the hosts file based on the history of the broswer. It is some kind of espionage, but it is for good

Comment: By the way, @martineau I will test your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the hosts file is really cludgy old tech and playing catchup after the fact.

You might want to try using DNS services with built in site blocking. OpenDNS does site blocking but it's more robust in commercial products. Researching this, I ran into Norton ConnectSafe (dns.norton.com), free for home use. It has porn and non-family blocking options with specific DNS numbers. They maintain the site list for you.

Ideally, you'd set the DNS servers on the router they don't have access to but it will affect all connected computers. DNS can also be set per PC though.

This won't avoid everything but would make your job easier?