# Chrome Incognito mode save history

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

i have simple question, is here some option how to trace google chrome history in incognito mode? Some extension, settings, extra software or maybe some files stored in temp files?

Comment: You could use paper and pencil.

Comment: Depending on what it is you want, disabling might be easier? (I imagine you want to prevent people from doing things you can not see) If so, check this out: http://superuser.com/questions/189327/how-can-i-disable-private-browsing-incognito-mode-in-browser-x

Comment: @MrHug its a bit parental control. I know i can disable it, but when you disable something, kids will find way how to overcome that. By this i will know if they do something bad.

Comment: @LubosSuk Fair enough ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory it's possible for an extension to track what you're doing in incognito. By default all extensions are disabled in incognito mode, probably for the very reason that they could potentially track you, but they can be set to 'enabled in incognito'.

A simplier solution might be to capture all traffic flowing through your network or to use a keylogger.

Comment: Nice ideas, i thought about keylogger too, but it will capture only keypressed. I would rather to log some specific pages. Can you reccomend something to capture trafic please?

Comment: It depends on what you need it for, must it be hidden or need an admin account to disable? Or is this for some sort of debug/monitoring?

Comment: just for monitoring. better hidden, but it isnt must. and admin rights are unimportant

Comment: I'd suggest to use something like opendns.com, other solutions are a bit more convoluted.

Alternatively you can *disable* incognito mode for chrome.